# *.h5 Projection Parameters

Tags: python, coordinate-system, georeferencing, proj

I have a file named 'VNP13A1...h5' and I'm trying to georeference it in Python 3. I know how to read and extract data from this file and what I'm trying to do is automating this process for other files as well.

This is what I did so far

```py
from h5py import File
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np

file    = File(i_file, 'r')
file_md = file['HDFEOS INFORMATION/StructMetadata.0'][()].split()
file_md = [md.decode('utf-8') for md in file_md]

for md in file_md:
    if 'UpperLeftPointMtrs=(' in md:
        mtrs   = md.split('=', 1)[1]
        ulc    = np.fromstring(mtrs[1:-1], dtype=float, sep=',')
    elif 'LowerRightMtrs=(' in md:
        mtrs   = md.split('=', 1)[1]
        lrc    = np.fromstring(mtrs[1:-1], dtype=float, sep=',')
    elif 'XDim=' in md:
        mtrs   = md.split('=', 1)[1]
        width  = float(mtrs)
    elif 'YDim=' in md:
        mtrs   = md.split('=', 1)[1]
        height = float(mtrs)

res   = np.divide(np.subtract(lrc, ulc), (width, height))
prj4  = '+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs'
trans = rio.Affine.translation(*ulc) * rio.Affine.scale(*res)
```

For this specific file proj4 value is

```py
+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs
```

I searched the metadata and found this

```py
`file_md[:15]

['GROUP=SwathStructure',
 'END_GROUP=SwathStructure',
 'GROUP=GridStructure',
 'GROUP=GRID_1',
 'GridName="NPP_Grid_16Day_VI_500m"',
 'XDim=2400',
 'YDim=2400',
 'UpperLeftPointMtrs=(3335851.559000,4447802.078667)',
 'LowerRightMtrs=(4447802.078667,3335851.559000)',
 'Projection=HE5_GCTP_SNSOID',
 'ProjParams=(6371007.181000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)',
 'SphereCode=-1',
 'GROUP=Dimension',
 'END_GROUP=Dimension',
 'GROUP=DataField']
```

What I can say about 'ProjParams=(6371007.181000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)' is that I think 6371007.181000 is related to radius of the ellipsoid used in this projection but nothing else.

What are those other values used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the Sinusoidal projection parameters for the USGS General Cartographic Transformation Package (GCTP):

1 Radius of sphere of reference
2 Not used
3 Not used
4 Not used
5 Longitude of central meridian
6 Not used
7 False easting applied to all coordinates
8 False northing applied to all coordinates
9 Not used...

https://www.cmascenter.org/ioapi/documentation/all_versions/html/GCTP.pdf

Comment: Just to add for completeness that the EPSG code for this projection is 53008 (https://epsg.io/53008).

Comment: Thanks a million times to you for your answer and the source. This is definitely what I was looking for, I cannot wait to learn more from this source! And about that EPSG code, I don't think EPSG 53008 is really the projection in which I am working. In this data, radius of the sphere is 6371007.181000 m but in EPSG 53008 it is just 6371000 m

Comment: @pan 53008 is NOT an EPSG Code (code defined by EPSG). The authority for the code is ESRI